# How do you create a custom WPTouch theme?

Tags: themes, css, plugin-wptouch

I have WPTouch Pro installed and it does a great job at device detection as well as handling most blog posts.  However, I want to make a mobile version of a homepage that doesn't have any blog posts.  I know you can edit the css for a theme by making a child theme and editing it.  Is this the preferred method to get WPTouch to show more content from the original page?

That link is here: http://www.koolkatwebdesigns.com/wptouch-and-custom-templates/

Also, someone is using shortcodes; not sure if this works for content that WPTouch is already ignoring: http://www.renegadetechconsulting.com/tutorials/generate-mobile-specific-content-using-wptouch-pro-shortcodes

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) as for any other theme. This way you can

- extend the functionality
- override stuff that's wrapped inside a `if ( ! function_exists('function_name') )` statement in the parent themes functions.php
- override templates

There should be no real difference between such themes and normal themes.